# Python 3.x - printing a diamond with no fill using strings

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a function, diamond(num), where num is the size of the 'diamond' that is made up of forward/backward slashes and spaces.
E.g.

```
>>> diamond(3)
   /\
  /  \
 /    \
 \    /
  \  /
   \/

>>> diamond(2)
  /\
 /  \
 \  /
  \/

>>> diamond(1)
 /\
 \/
```

However, I feel like my code is too complicated. Is there a simpler way of doing this?

```
def reverse(value,end):
    if end %2 != 0:
        return None
    MAX = end/2
    START = (end/2)-1
    turningPoint = (end/2)+1
    numbers = {}
    second = -MAX
    for x in range(1,end+1):
        if x < turningPoint:
            numbers[x] = START-(2*(x-1))
        if x >= turningPoint:
            numbers[x] = second
    return value + numbers[value]


def diamond(length):
    output = ''
    MAX = length
    length *= 2
    if length == 0 or length % 2 != 0:
        return None
    for x in range(1,length+1):
        var = int(reverse(x,length))
        if x < MAX+1:
            output += ' '*var + '/' + ' '*((MAX-var)*2) + '\\' + '\n'
        else:
            output += ' '*var + '\\' + ' '*((MAX-var)*2) + '/' + '\n'
    return print(output)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I recommend the following function?

```
def get_diamond(size):
    return '\n'.join([' ' * (size - i - 1) + '/' + '  ' * i + '\\'
                      for i in range(size)] +
                     [' ' * (size - i - 1) + '\\' + '  ' * i + '/'
                      for i in reversed(range(size))])
```

You can use it like so:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(get_diamond(i + 1))
```

After running the code, your screen should look like this:

```
/\
\/
 /\
/  \
\  /
 \/
  /\
 /  \
/    \
\    /
 \  /
  \/
   /\
  /  \
 /    \
/      \
\      /
 \    /
  \  /
   \/
    /\
   /  \
  /    \
 /      \
/        \
\        /
 \      /
  \    /
   \  /
    \/
```

If you do not mind something a bit more convoluted, this function does the same as the first:

```
def get_diamond(s):
    return '\n'.join(' ' * (s - w - 1) + a + '  ' * w + z for a, z, r in (
        ('/', '\\', range(s)), ('\\', '/', reversed(range(s)))) for w in r)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

```
def printDiamond(n):
       upperHalf = ""
       lowerHalf = ""

       for row in range(1, n + 1):
              outerSpaces = n - row
              innerSpaces = 2*row - 2

              rowTempl = outerSpaces * " " + "{c1}" + innerSpaces * " " + "{c2}" + "\n"

              upperHalf += rowTempl.format(c1='/', c2='\\')
              lowerHalf = rowTempl.format(c1='\\', c2='/') + lowerHalf

       print(upperHalf + lowerHalf)

printDiamond(1)    
printDiamond(2)
printDiamond(5)
printDiamond(7)
```

Output:

```
/\
\/

 /\
/  \
\  /
 \/

    /\
   /  \
  /    \
 /      \
/        \
\        /
 \      /
  \    /
   \  /
    \/

      /\
     /  \
    /    \
   /      \
  /        \
 /          \
/            \
\            /
 \          /
  \        /
   \      /
    \    /
     \  /
      \/
```

Comment: Does not return the expected outcome :/