# Issue with my print diamond code in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been tasked with printing a diamond made of *, given a natural number n. The number of rows is equal to 2n and number of columns is equal to 2n + 2. I don't need help finishing this code, rather I need help figuring out what the error is in my current code.

```
import check

def acc_fn(rows,stars,columns):

    if rows > 2: 
        print(stars + '-' * (columns - rows -1)  + ('*' * rows) + '-' * \
              (columns - rows -1))
        return acc_fn(rows -2 , stars, columns -1)
    else:
        print(stars + '-' * (columns - rows -1)  + ('*' * rows) + '-' * \
              (columns - rows -1))

def printdiamond (n):

    return acc_fn(2*n,'', 2*n +2) 

check.set_screen( "-**********-\n-**********-\n--********--\n---******---\
                 \n----****----\n-----**-----")
check.expect("Q3T1", printdiamond(5), None)
```

So what should be output:

```
-**********-
--********--
---******---                 
----****----
-----**-----
```

Right now what is outputting:

```
-**********-
--********--
---******---
----****----
-----**-----
-----
```

The issue seems to be with the print line, but I can't determine it for the life of me. Also I realize this isn't a diamond, but my next after determining this error would be due to the top half of the diamond. I have an idea on how to do this so I don't need help with that.

Comment: cannot reproduce. Seems to work fine. Note that you don't return anything but just print.

Comment: Yeah I'm not supposed to return anything with this function. But it shouldn't have those dashes at the end.

Comment: I can guarantee that I _don't_ have it in my output. I get a clean diamond.

Comment: Alright I believe you. However, what could be causing this? Should I re-install python? Maybe it's a difference in the text editors we are using?

Comment: reinstalling python isn't going to change a thing. I don't know. I have added the generic "python" tag so the question is more visible

Comment: Thank you Jean-F

Comment: It's not really relevant. But basically it tests whether your code works or not. Prints passed if it does, failed and what was actually returned if it doesn't. Example: the check.expect() above returns passed, since my expected return value is None, and that is what is actually seen.

Comment: _"It's not really relevant."_ I disagree with this because calling `printdiamond(5)` by itself seems to work (at least for me). Therefore something must be going on in `check` but no one knows what.

Comment: Oh my god that's like rule number 1. Never rule anything it out. And you're right. it works without the check expect. God damn it. Thanks man. Now I know its a check module issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.x - printing a diamond with no fill using strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798769/python-3-x-printing-a-diamond-with-no-fill-using-strings)

Answer (score 0):

I just want to post this in case some one runs into a similar issue, or rather is as confused as I was.What happened here is a misunderstanding of the structure of this module. The check module aids in testing your code. Check.set_screen takes an input, which is the expected print outcome of the check.expect test. The check expect module however tests what is returned by the function. The reason why at the end of the diamond, there was an extra line of -----, was because each check.set_screen and check expect test set ends with this printed line to indicate the end of the print output.